# Dynamic variable names - Actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

I would like to dynamically create elements based on the array. I would like to just put the array name and append _panel ...so menu_item_panel will become settings_panel, info_panel,etc. I cannot figure out how to do that?

```
var menu_items:Array = new Array("settings","info","debug","Feedback");
var menu_items_count:Number = menu_items.length;

var menu_height:Number = c.height / menu_items_count;
var menu_height_int:Number = 0;

for (var i:int=0; i<menu_items_count; i++)
{
    var menu_item_panel:Sprite = new Sprite();
menu_item_panel.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 1);
menu_item_panel.graphics.drawRect(0, menu_height, c.width, menu_height);
menu_item_panel.graphics.endFill();
menu_panel.addChild(menu_item_panel);
menu_panel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,menu_panel_click);
menu_height_int = menu_height_int + menu_height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you set the `name` property of the `Sprite` object to the name of the menu item.

```
menu_item_panel.name = menu_items[i];
```

Then in your `click` handler you check the `name` property of `event.target` and perform the appropriate action based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (var i:int=0; i<menu_items_count; i++)
{
    var menu_item_panel:Sprite = new Sprite();
    menu_item_panel.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 1);
    menu_item_panel.graphics.drawRect(0, menu_height, c.width, menu_height);
    menu_item_panel.graphics.endFill();
    menu_panel.addChild(menu_item_panel);
    menu_panel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(){});
    menu_height_int = menu_height_int + menu_height;
    // Store the new clip in a var
    this[menu_items[i]+"_panel"] = menu_item_panel;
}
// get the clips
trace(this.settings_panel);
trace(this.info_panel);
trace(this.debug_panel);
trace(this.Feedback_panel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
for (...)
{
    //...
    menu_item_panel.name = menu_items[i]+"_panel";
    menu_panel[menu_item_panel.name] = menu_panel.addChild(menu_item_panel);
    //...
}
```

That's because two things:

```
// This line set the name of the item to "settings_panel", "info_panel", etc
menu_item_panel.name = menu_items[i]+"_panel";

// This line add menu_item_panel as a child of menu_panel
// and set the property called "settings_panel", "info_panel", etc
// to the right panel
menu_panel[menu_item_panel.name] = menu_panel.addChild(menu_item_panel);
```

So when you run this line:

```
menu_panel.settings_panel;
```

You are obtaining the menu item called "settings_panel"

This type of setting:

```
object[string] = property;
```

Works for all objects that are declared `dynamic` (`MovieClip` and `Object` are `dynamic`). That's the way to add (dinamically) properties to an object in run-time.

Comment: Sprites **ARE NOT** dynamics!

Comment: NemoStein it appears you are correct. I get the following error: ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property settings_panel on flash.display.Sprite.

Comment: Sorry, answer edited. You're right. I wrote that from my memory. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a class and extend the sprite class then you can make it as dynamic as you need.

Comment: Ah my bad, after looking at the answer above I see I misunderstood what you were looking to do. Ignore this answer :) Also if you are getting into writing actionscript you might want to look into and read up on how class files are made, since actionscript is an object oriented programing language and class files are the basis for OOP. Having a good understanding of classes is key to becoming a great programmer with any OOP language.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding the following and it appears to work. I'm not sure why I have to put "this" anywhere.

```
this[menu_items[i]+"_panel"] = menu_item_panel;
    menu_panel.addChild(this[menu_items[i]+"_panel"]);
```

And I can make it visible by saying:

```
 this.settings_panel.visible = false;
```

Comment: Not sure I can explain this good but will give it a shot.The "this" keyword is defining the scope. In your case menu_items is an array with elements. the first element menu_items[0] has a string value of 'settings', by doing this['settings' +'_panel'] you are saying there is a property of settings_panel in the current scope. without the "this" ['settings_panel'] there is no identifier so the compiler will not know where to look for the property.